# Wind Wall & Control Wind combo

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

Wind wall cast first creates a severe updraft. Control Winds raises mild wind speed up to severe in same area.

Would the Control Winds spell raise the wind wall air speed to tornado strength? And, if so, would medium creatures that move into the Wind Wall be blown up to the top of the Wall?

Comment: I don't see in the *wind wall* spell's description that it produces the equivalent of the *Dungeon Master's Guide* severe wind force. (In fact, it seems to omit entirely the *wall*'s degree of wind force.) Is that wind force an extrapolation based on the spell's description or do you've more information about the spell from another source?

Comment: _Wind Wall_'s description says "It is 2 feet thick and of considerable strength". However, it then goes on to say "It is a roaring blast sufficient to blow away any bird smaller than an eagle, or tear papers and similar materials from unsuspecting hands.", which as little as a strong breeze is capable of.

Answer (score 2):

No, because *Wind Wall* doesn't produce wind of quite that strength.  Extrapolating from the size of creature blown away ("Anything smaller than an Eagle") and the facts that an Eagle is a Small creature and flying creatures are treated as one category smaller for wind effects, we can see that the *Wind Wall*, even if we allow that its wind speed is just barely insufficient to blow away an eagle, has a maximum wind speed of 30 mph, or 'strong'.  That means that adding *control winds* merely increases the strength to Hurricane force, rather than Tornado.  Nonetheless, that's enough to potentially blow away medium-sized creatures who interact with the wall and fail their save.  It's unclear what direction a Medium grounded creature would be 'rolled' but a flying Medium creature is 'blown back' which does indeed seem to indicate they would be moved upwards 2d6*10 feet and take 2d6 non-lethal damage.  The upwards motion has no correlation to the height of the wall, however.